# как изменить строку в объекте через setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socketio-client

[image: объект в котором надо изменить нужную строчку]

нужно поменять значение id на пустую строку
делаю setState({ idToName[id]: ""})
выходит ошибка 
что делать?
стэйт

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        idToName:{},
    };
}
```

метод

```
idtoname = (id) => {
const { idToName } = this.state;
if(id in idToName) {
    return idToName[id];
} else {
    this.setState({ idToName[id]})
    this.loadname(id);
    return "";
}
```

}

изменил строчку вот так

```
idToName[id] = "";
this.setState({ idToName })
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: я привел часть кода в котором описана суть проблемы.

Comment: Приведите более полный фрагмент вашего кода, текстом (не картинкой). Приведите точный текст ошибки. Опишите вашу цель, что и для чего вы хотите сделать.

Comment: поправил но сам объект не картинкой не могу вывести тк это скрин с консоли

Comment: Текст ошибки приведите еще, плиз

Comment: сделал. вроде работает

Comment: Что вы сделали, разместите как ответ. Если причина в опечатке - вопрос стоит удалить.

Comment: idToName[id] = "";
this.setState({ idToName })

Comment: Присваивание значения таким образом это плохая идея, потому что объект сохраняет ссылку на стейт, и получается что вы пытаетесь изменить стейт напрямую.

Answer (score 3):

Вы передаёте в `this.setState` неправильный объект, попробуйте следующим образом:

```
idtoname = (id) => {
  const { idToName } = this.state;
  if(id in idToName) {
    return idToName[id];
  } else {
    this.setState({
      ...idToName,
      id: ""
    })
    this.loadname(id);
    return "";
  }
```